# Cypress JS using multiple page objects in one method

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, pageobjects, chainable

i have been struggling with some logic about using  multiple page objects in one method, i couldnt find any idea to use like that logic, for example;

**These are my methods in my page object called usersTable;**

```
 get rolesAndStatusMenu() {
    return cy.get("#menu- > .MuiPaper-root > .MuiMenu-list>li");
  }

  get usersPartialRow() {
    return cy.get(".MuiTableBody-root>tr>td");
  }

settings(options: string) {
    return cy
      .get(
        "[style='position: fixed; z-index: 1300; inset: 0px;'] > .MuiPaper-root > .MuiList-root",
      )
      .contains(options);
  }

  menuButton(userId: string) {
    return cy.get(`.user_${userId}>td>button`);
  }

  userRow(userId?: string) {
    const userrow = ".MuiTableBody-root>tr";

    if (userId === undefined) {
      return cy.get(userrow);
    }

    return cy.get(userrow).get(`.user_${userId}`);
  }
```

**im using userRow method in this test like that;**

```
usersTable.userRow(userId).should("not.exist");
```

**And for exaple im using my userMenu and settings method in this test;**

```
usersTable.menuButton(userId).click();
usersTable.settings("Impersonate").click();
```

**Let's come to the idea that I want to do but I can't find the way to do it;**

```
usersTable.userRow(userId).settings.menuButton.click()

usersTable.userRow(userId).settings.impersonate.click()
```

**Is there a any way to use like that ? All ideas are accepted**

**Update**

I have one more page object, i define my usersTable component modal inside called usersPage page modal

```
    import { UsersTable } from "../components/UsersTable ";
    
    export class Users {
      visit() {
        return cy.visit("/users");
      }
      get headingText() {
        return cy.get(".MuiTypography-h5");
      }
      get inviteUserBtn() {
        return cy.get(".MuiGrid-root> .MuiButtonBase-root");
      }
      get inviteUserModal() {
        return cy.get(".MuiDialogContent-root");
      }
    get usersTable() {
    return new UsersTable();
  }
    }
```

**So my code looks like this**

```
usersPage.usersTable.menuButton(userId).click();
usersPage.usersTable.settings("Impersonate").click();
usersPage.visit();
usersPage.usersTable.menuButton(userId).click();
usersPage.usersTable.settings("Delete").click();
usersPage.usersTable.userRow(userId).should("not.exist");
```

**For example using this way**

```
usersPage.usersTable.userRow(userId).settings.menuButton.click()
```

**So maybe i can create class inside `UsersTable`**

```
export class UsersTable {
...
}
class userTableRow {
}
**and returning it in `UsersTable` or something like that ?**
```

**Second Update**

Now i create a class inside `UsersTable` file;

```
class UserRow {
  userRow(userId?: string) {
    const userrow = ".MuiTableBody-root>tr";
    if (userId === undefined) {
      return cy.get(userrow);
    }

    return cy.get(userrow).find(`.user_${userId}`);
  }
  get menuButton() {
    return this.userRow(`>td>button`); //Btw im not sure this one is working, i think something is wrong here;
  }
  get impersonate() {
    return cy
      .get(
        "[style='position: fixed; z-index: 1300; inset: 0px;'] > .MuiPaper-root > .MuiList-root",
      )
      .contains("Impersonate");
  }
  get delete() {
    return cy
      .get(
        "[style='position: fixed; z-index: 1300; inset: 0px;'] > .MuiPaper-root > .MuiList-root",
      )
      .contains("Delete");
  }
}
```

And for using this class  **`returned`** in **`UsersTable`** class;

```
 userRow(userId?: string) {
    const userrow = ".MuiTableBody-root>tr";

    if (userId === undefined) {
      return cy.get(userrow);
    }

    return new UserRow(userId); **// but got error, it says Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.**
  }
```

**If i use like this comment section;**

```
 // get UserRow() {
  //   return new UserRow();  
  // }
```

**I can able to reach everything inside user but i can't use my test like this;**

```
   usersPage.usersTable.UserRow(userId).settings.menuButton.click()
```

**or maybe**

```
usersPage.usersTable.UserRow.userRow(userId).settings.menuButton.click()
```

**But i can use like this;**

```
 usersPage.usersTable.UserRow.menuButton.click()
```

How can i define `userId?: string`  for `UserRow`  **userId** is constantly changing every time,  I get it from API inside test, So I can't define for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, @Fody @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR  but can I do something like this? if i  create a class called `UserTableRow` in the same file **(userTable.ts)** and return it, and define those functions here? If I need that line directly in the test;
Maybe i can use `usersTable.userRow(userId).row` or `usersTable.userRow(userId).root`

Comment: Can you add some example code to the question to clarify?

Comment: Looks like the same problem will occur. `userRow(userId)` has no method or property `settings`.

Comment: So i can't create `userRow(user Id)` class and attend `settings` method in it ? isnt it possible?

Comment: From what I can see `userRow(user Id)` is a method on `UserTable` that currently returns `cy.get(userrow)`. Whatever it returns must have a method `settings` for `userRow(userId).settings()` to work.

Comment: Its fair, I'm out of ideas :/

Comment: I'm not really sure why you like that pattern, it's not very flexible. There are loads of places in tests where you need to tweak/transform the results and `.then()` is very useful for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `UserTable` methods return the `Cypress.Chainable` type, so you will need to unwrap the result to pass it to the next method.

Also, it's returning the element but next method needs text content, so extract that as well.

```js
usersTable.userRow(userId)
  .then((userIdElement: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {  // unwrap Chainable
    const text = userIdElement.text()              // extract text
    usersTable.settings(text)
  })
  .then((settingsElement: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {  // unwrap Chainable
    const text = settingsElement.text()              // extract text
    usersTable.menuButton(text).click()
  })
```

If any of the elements are `HTMLInputElement`, use `userIdElement.val()` instead.

An adjustment to userRow():

```js
class UsersTable {

  ...

  userRow(userId?: string): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {  
    const userrow = ".MuiTableBody-root>tr";

    if (userId === undefined) {
      return cy.get(userrow);
    }

    return cy.get(userrow)
      .find(`.user_${userId}`)  // use find instead of get
  }
}
```

---

#### How to do it with Custom Commands instead of pageObject

Chaining is a natural code pattern for Cypress commands, so using Custom Commands

**commands.js**

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
    settings(options?: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
    menuButton(userId?: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
    userRow(userId?: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('settings', {prevSubject: 'optional'}, (subject: any, options?: string): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>  => {
  if (options === undefined) {
    options = subject as string;
  }
  return cy.get("[style='position: fixed; z-index: 1300; inset: 0px;'] > .MuiPaper-root > .MuiList-root")
    .contains(options)
})

Cypress.Commands.add('menuButton', {prevSubject: 'optional'}, (subject: any, userId?: string): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> => {
  if (userId === undefined) {
    userId = subject as string;
  }
  return cy.get(`.user_${userId}>td>button`);
})

Cypress.Commands.add('userRow', (userId?: string): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> => {
  const userrow = ".MuiTableBody-root>tr";

  if (userId === undefined) {
    return cy.get(userrow);
  }

  return cy.get(userrow)
    .find(`.user_${userId}`)
})
```

**test**

```js
it('tests with userId from userRow()', () => {
  const userId = '1'

  cy.userRow(userId)
    .settings()      // as child command, userId from previous command
    .menuButton()
    .click()
});

it('tests with userId hard-coded', () => {

  cy.settings('abc')    // as parent command, userId passed as parameter
    .menuButton()
    .click()
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, in this case im not going to edit my page objects right? But  i need to edit my page object methods for using that logic i mentioned

Comment: I'm suggesting editing the test, pageObject is mostly the same (I added return type for clarity).

Comment: I tried a solution using modified pageObject, problem is to chain methods like `usersTable.userRow(userId).settings.menuButton.click()` the methods need to return `this` which is the instance of the pageObject. But then you can't return the result of the Cypress commands inside the method.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there is a way, but I couldn't find it despite my research, I guess it doesn't seem possible to chain it like this?

Comment: I thought about adding class instance properties for `userId` result and `setting` to capture results of each method, but above seemed cleaner solution.

Comment: Your solution is also a different point of view, of course, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To make class methods fluid, you will need to return `this`.

```js
class UsersTable {

  settings(options: string) {
    cy.get(...).contains(options);
    return this                         // call next method on return value
  }

  menuButton(userId: string) {
    return cy.get(`.user_${userId}>td>button`); // cannot call another after this one
  }

  userRow(userId?: string) {
    cy.get(userrow).get(`.user_${userId}`);
    return this;                              // call next method on return value
  }
}
```

Should work,

```js
usersTable.userRow(userId).settings().menuButton().click()
```

But now, where are the values from first two methods?

You would need to store them in the class

```js
class UsersTable {

  userId: string = '';
  setting: string = '';

  settings(options: string) {
    cy.get(...).contains(options)
      .invoke('text')
      .then(text => this.setting = text)

    return this                        
  }

  menuButton() {                       // no parameter, take value from field
    return cy.get(`.user_${this.setting}>td>button`); 
  }

  userRow() {            // no parameter, take value from field
    cy.get(userrow).get(`.user_${this.userId}`)
      .invoke('text')
      .then(text => this.userId = text)

    return this;                              // call next method on return value
  }
}
```

But now have lost flexibility, methods are ***tightly coupled***, not independent anymore.